# Spring: Overriding/Mocking dependency's dependency

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mocking

Running test cases on a project is taking an inordinate amount of time. In diagnosing this issue, we have determined that a certain service call is dragging its digital feet. We would like to mock it out via Spring as we have done in other projects, however this project makes the service call vicariously (it calls a project, who calls a project, who calls the service; each with their own spring configs).

Project Alpha -> Project Bravo -> Service Foo from Project Charlie

Question:
Will modifications to the Spring config in Project Alpha allow mocking out Service Foo or will the Spring config in Project Bravo be unaffected by configurations outside its .war file.

Note: This could easily be accomplished by placing the mock config in Project Bravo yet that is not an option in this case.

Comment: can't you mock the service call with something like EasyMock?

Comment: @AnthonyW: build the different projects one single spring application (one single spring-context)?

Comment: Project Bravo is used by several other teams. Changing or recompiling it is not an option.

Comment: I am attempting to mock the service now but not seeing any effect. What i need to know is if it is a personal problem (something I can fix) or a limitation of Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Stone age version

[Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home)

> This is a small extension to spring that simplifies way of creation mockito mocks in the intergation tests' related context xml files.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mockito="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito.xsd">
...
    <mockito:mock id="innerBean" class="my.project.InnerBean" />
..
</beans>
```

### New Age version

Try @ReplaceWithMock annotation

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,
locations = "classpath:/context.xml")
public class SpringockitoAnnotationsMocksIntegrationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @ReplaceWithMock
    @Autowired
    private InnerBean innerBean;

...
}
```

https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations

Comment: Forgot to mention we are still stuck in the stone age (pre-annotations).